# Regex string for phrase

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract a ticket number with the phrase "Ticket ID: (20 digit number)"
This phrase can be written as:

- "Ticket ID: (20 digit number)"
- "TicketID:(20 digit number)" - Spaces do not matter

Here is the regex string I am using that fails to work.  I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong here.  This regex should be looking for any phrases reguardless of space with the word Ticket followed by ID: followed by a 20 digit number of any kind.

```
Regex newExpression = new Regex(@"\bTicket\b.*\bID:\b.*\d{20}", 
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase 
                | RegexOptions.Singleline
                | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: So what’s wrong with the regular expression you have? Is it not matching, or do you need to know how to make groups, or…?

Comment: Its not matching the phrases I have mentioned above.  when use the phrase "testestetaette Ticket ID: (20 digit Number) dwadwdwdwfwfw" it does not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this pattern you obtain directly the number since the lookbehind `(?<=..)` is just a check and is not in the match result:

```
Regex newExpression = new Regex(@"(?<=\bTicket\s*ID\s*:\s*)\d{20}", 
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

A word boundary doesn’t happen after a `:`. Just use `\s*` to ignore spaces:

```
Regex newExpression = new Regex(@"Ticket\s*ID:\s*(\d{20})");
```

Now you can use `newExpression.Match(someString).Groups[1].Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip everything before the `:` or `:`, like

```
@".*\s*\d{20}"
```

Comment: Any number of anything, followed by any number of spaces, followed by twenty digits? Why not just 20 digits?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try this code. It captures the 20 digit number as **named** capture group in `Regex`:

```
var newExpression = new Regex(//@"\bTicket\b.*\bID:\b.*\d{20}", 
                @"Ticket\s*ID\:\s*(?<num>\(\d{20}\))",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase 
                | RegexOptions.Singleline
                | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

var items=new List<string>();
var r=new Random();
var sb=new StringBuilder();
var i=0;
var formats=new []{"TicketID:({0})", "Ticket ID:({0})", "Ticket ID: ({0})", 
               "Ticket ID: ({0})"};
for(;i<5;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<20;j++){
        sb.Append(r.Next(0,9));
    }
    items.Add(string.Format(formats[r.Next(0,4)],sb));
    sb.Remove(0,20);
}

for(;i<10;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<20;j++){
        sb.Append(r.Next(0,9));
    }
    items.Add(string.Format(formats[r.Next(0,2)],sb));
    sb.Remove(0,20);
}

for(;i<15;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<20;j++){
        sb.Append(r.Next(0,9));
    }
    items.Add(string.Format(formats[r.Next(0,2)],sb));
    sb.Remove(0,20);
}

foreach(var s in items){
    var m = newExpression.Match(s);
    if(m.Success && m.Groups!=null && m.Groups.Count>0){
        string.Format("{0} - {1}",s,m.Groups["num"].Value).Dump();
    }
}
```

NOTE: This was ran in Linqpad.